# propensity score matching and survival analysis

Tags: r, survival, propensity-scores

I am using the `Matching` R package to compute Average Treatment Effect within Propensity Score Matching (PSM).

I have two groups: treatment and control. In addition to assessing the statistical difference between these groups on standard continuous variables, I need to verify if the two survival curves are the same between the two groups.

Before knowing PSM I had used the classical log - rank test. How can I update my approach taking into account PSM (possibly using the Matching R package)?

Comment: Would it to simple to say: Do as you always do, only use the matched sample in place of the "raw" one? This, at least, is the main point from the authors of MatchIT in R (Ho, King, Garry and Imai). "Matching does not add addtional parametric assumptions, but does not reduce them either".

Comment: Can you expand on your query "I need to verify if the two survival curves are the same within groups"? Not sure what the within-group element here refers to...

Comment: @James... you are right. I have edided.